# Overriding user edit profile form

Tags: php, drupal-6, edit, user-profile

Im using `theme_user_profile_form($form)` and putting in the line

```
unset ($form['timezone']);
```

But it doesnt remove that item from the page

I try:

```
theme_preprocess_user_profile_form
```

but it doesnt appear to work.

All I want to do is remove some portions of the user profile edit form, such as theme select, timezone etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it, is to use `hook_form_alter`. This needs to be in a custom module and not in your theme.

Comment: I try unset ($form['timezone']); in the hook_form_alter and doesnt remove that item from the page in drupal7.  What is my error???

Comment: @cabita Maybe you didn't pass the form by reference using `&`

Comment: This is my code in drupal 7:  function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
if($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
unset($form['account']['timezone']);} and doesn't remove that item from the page.  Thanks for your answer and your help.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is that you have to do that hook form alter, but do the unset in the after build of the form i.e.

```
function example_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   $form["#after_build"][] = "example";
}

function example($form, &$form_state) {`
    //dpm($form); /*devel module dependency for looking for the correct object*/
    //unset
    return $form;
}
```